# Meteor routing returning "[object Object]"

Tags: javascript, meteor

I am currently going through the Discover Meteor book and got an unexpected result that differs from the result that the book is suggesting.

Just after installing the iron router I followed the book and connected `router.js` with `layout.html` but I get `[object Object]` as a result instead of the posts.

my code :

**layout.html**

```
<template name="layout">
  <div class="container">
    <header class="navbar">
      <div class="navbar-inner">
        <a class="brand" href="{{pathFor 'postsList'}}">Microscope</a>
      </div>
    </header>
    <div id="main" class="row-fluid">
      {{yield}}
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**router.js**

```
Router.configure({
  layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function() {
  this.route('postsList', {path: '/'});
});
```

Comment: Try to use `{{> yield}}` instead.

Comment: should put something about what you expected the output to be ( from the book )

Comment: adding the > worked, thx! they got a typo in the book I guess

Comment: I'm not sure if this counts as a typo or not. Anyway, @RafaelQuintanilha, you should post this as an answer.